# Simple way to convert modern ES2017 to ES5 with Babel for browsers using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, transpiler

I've been trying to transpile my ES8 code (using all the modern *syntactical* features, including async/await) to ES5 using Babel. But it's been giving me a headache. Either, some variables aren't defined and require me to install some sort of polyfill (I don't want to polyfill anything, I just want to convert **syntax**, which is what Babel promises), OR the source code gets filled with require() statements that obviously browsers can't execute. I don't want CommonJS, I want plain browser-compatible JavaScript.

I'm running Babel just by itself, no Webpack or stuff like that.

I've searched wide and far. What's the simplest setup using Node.js to get this running?

Comment: The simplest way is babel-node. The problem depends on your setup which wasn't shown. There's no such thing as ES8. If you're referring to ES2017, it's already supported by Node natively.

Comment: I meant ES2017. I'm not concerned about Node supporting that code, I'm trying to get my code browser-ready.

Comment: "*All the modern features*" do include some values that need to be polyfilled, not just syntax. There's no way around using the polyfill.

Comment: *I don't want CommonJS, I want plain browser-compatible JavaScript.* - why? If you want it to run in browser then you asked the wrong question. This is not *in Node* anymore. And you need Webpack or other bundler in addition to Babel for that, that's their job.

Comment: @estus The title says **in Node**, not **for Node**. With that I mean I wanna use it programatically and not via a CLI.

Comment: Is there a real need to run it programmatically? Most setups you will see use CLI because it suits most cases. Any way, it's a bundler that you need, not only Babel. See https://webpack.js.org/api/node/ if you really need to use it programmatically.

Comment: @estus Most CLI tools are just node.js scripts, so not much difference there :-)

Comment: Well. I wanna avoid using Webpack because I'm making my own bundler adjusted for my personal needs and for just learning how it works. However, it's missing the "Transpile to a lower JavaScript version" step, hence me trying out Babel. Is there some way to replace those require() statements without Webpack, or force Babel to inject the code? Or is there an alternative to Babel?

Comment: Also, isn't it kinda shitty that Babel doesn't work completely standalone? These intertwined npm packages are really grinding my gears at this point.

Comment: @Bergi Some were primarily designed to run as CLI like `npm`, This is not the case for Babel or popular bundlers AFAIK, but CLI provides a convention over configuration, a dev is on his/her own when using them programmatically.

Comment: *Is there some way to replace those require() statements without Webpack, or force Babel to inject the code?* - this is the work for a bundler, not a transpiler. They are different tools for different purposes. If you didn't have much experience with a toolchain, it's likely too early to invent your own wheel. There are alternatives to Babel but they don't work differently in this regard. Transpile modules with a transpiler. Glue them together with a bundler. If you don't like Webpack, you can use Rollup or else. If they don't suit your needs, there's a chance you don't use them properly.

Comment: I've thought about using Rollup. Problem is, it requires an entry file. Babel just returns me the transpiled source code. So what, do I have to create a new file in the right folder, run Rollup on that, get the source code, and delete the file again when done? That doesn't sound like the directest of solutions.

Comment: And yeah, I'm new to these, however, I didn't find them very intuitive to use at all, and I felt like they forced me to change how I program or structure my files, and I didn't like that. The bundler should adjust to my style. But that's off-topic now.

Comment: @DavidsKanal Why do you think would you need to create an extra file when using rollup?

Comment: @DavidsKanal So requires Webpack. Entry file is entry point of your app or library. It's expected to already exist in `src`. You can take a look how third-party libs are usually structured.

Comment: @Bergi Because it only takes a file path as an input. I can't pass it source code directly. Or, if I can and I missed out how, how?

Comment: @DavidsKanal Ah, that's what you mean. Yes, it needs a file path in order to resolve imports correctly. But where does your input code come from if not from a source file?

Comment: @Bergi Basically, I'm bundling <source> tags in HTML files. Let's say an HTML file uses 20 scripts, then I basically concatenate those, create one bundle file, and replace the <script> tags with just one, pointing to that bundle. I'm running Babel on that big concatenated source code string, that's where it comes from. But I can't just put the result of that back into the HTML, because it's *polluted* with require() statements. Hence my question.

Comment: There should be a single top-level module (entry point) that uses all these scripts. In case these scripts should intercommunicate, it puts them all together and initializes the app. Otherwise it just imports them all and does nothing else. Use `@` if you want participants to receive notifications about comments.

Comment: @estus I think it's quite naive to think every project can be boiled down to one entry point. Especially websites made out of many, many HTML and JavaScript files. Libraries of course are usually always based on one entry point, but that's not the type of project I want to bundle. Anyway, we're getting off-topic. My problem boils down to me having one source code string, in which I want to resolve all require() statements. Rollup requires an input file though, so I don't see another way of creating that and deleting it again, but that's dirty.

Comment: *I don't see another way of creating that and deleting it again* - if you need it any way, why not create it in `src`? This is what entry point is. *I think it's quite naive to think every project can be boiled down to one entry point* - this is what we usually do. If it doesn't boil down to single entry because these different apps that aren't used together (in non-SPA scenario when foo script is used on foo page and bar script on bar page) then there should be *multiple* entry points. There should be entry points somewhere because otherwise `import` and `export` stop to make sense.